# When does a satellite 'meet' the same place of a rotating earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, satellites

I'm stuck with a problem on GPS:

[image]

What I tried is to calculate first turnaround time of the satellite. Secondly I calculated the angular speed of both trajectories. The conditions that need to be fulfilled are that $\cos(\theta1 * t) = \cos(\theta2 * t) $ and  $\sin(\theta1 * t) = \sin(\theta2 * t)$ with $\theta$ the angular velocity. Unfortunately I cannot solve this, besides that I think there is a more fundamental approach that I don't know of.

Could I please get feedback on this?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.